# webpage highlight more info box

Tags: javascript, html

Is anyone aware what this page [Arachnode.net](http://arachnode.net/) is using to provide the More Info when you highlight a word.

Answer (score 2):

Its using [CloudFlare Highlight](https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/highlight).